# iptables command to get bytes used by specific ip on port 443

Tags: linux, iptables, wifi, network-monitoring

I have hosted a WiFi network and i need to monitor data usage by every IP address on port 443(https)

Here is the iptables rule used to share INTERNET from eth0 to wlan0

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So, how can i monitor logs by IP to specific port?

Can anybody please help!

Thanks

Comment: I am able to get combined data usage by all ports using following rule :

**`sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 192.168.5.6 -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 80,20,21,25 -j ACCEPT`**

though there is '!' operator, i'm getting all bytes used by port 80,
am i missing anything?

Comment: Edit your question and add this information, instead of doing so in a comment.